# Why my Javascript file is not working at all?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

My website works fine and all javascript files also work in my computer, but after publishing to the server all files work except **super.js file.** Links in menu supposed to work but it shows just "#".

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/App_Themes/standart2/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/App_Themes/standart2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
**<script type="text/javascript" src="/App_Themes/standart2/js/super.js"></script>**
<script type="text/javascript" src="/newfiles/calendar/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/newfiles/slider/script/jquery.easing-1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/newfiles/slider/script/jquery.easing.compatibility.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/newfiles/slider/script/jquery.jcarousellite.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/newfiles/slider/script/jquery.jcarousellite.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/newfiles/slider/script/jquery.mousewheel-3.1.12.js"></script>
```

Here is a snippet code to my file [a link] (http://jsfiddle.net/programmer777/oxj69tum/embedded/result/)! i don't understand a problem, looked everywhere, but couldn't find a solution.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var menuLinksNew = $(".menuH>li>a");

    var pathname = $(location).attr('pathname');

    if (pathname.substring(1, 3) == "eng") {

        $(menuLinksNew[0]).attr("href", "/about");
        $(menuLinksNew[0]).text("About");

    }
    else if (pathname.substring(1, 3) == "fr") {

        $(menuLinksNew[0]).attr("href", "/about");
        $(menuLinksNew[0]).text('About');

    }

    var submenuNew1 = $(".menuH ul a");
    if (pathname.substring(1, 3) == "eng") {


        $(submenuNew1[0]).attr("href", "/eng/about/info");
        $(submenuNew1[0]).children("h5").text("blah");
        $(submenuNew1[1]).attr("href", "/eng/about/info/1");
        $(submenuNew1[1]).children("h5").text("blah");
        $(submenuNew1[2]).attr("href", "/eng/about/info");
        $(submenuNew1[2]).children("small").text('blah');
        $(submenuNew1[3]).attr("href", "/eng/about/info");
        $(submenuNew1[3]).children("small").text('blah');
     }
else if (pathname.substring(1, 3) == "fr") {

        $(submenuNew1[0]).attr("href", "/fr/about/info");
        $(submenuNew1[0]).children("h5").text("blah");
        $(submenuNew1[1]).attr("href", "/fr/about/info/1");
        $(submenuNew1[1]).children("h5").text("blah");
        $(submenuNew1[2]).attr("href", "/fr/about/info");
        $(submenuNew1[2]).children("small").text('blah');
        $(submenuNew1[3]).attr("href", "/fr/about/info");
        $(submenuNew1[3]).children("small").text('blah');

});
```

Comment: There might be some case sensitivity issue.

Comment: How can I solve sensitivity issue. :(

Comment: rename your file to super.js from Super.js or SUPER.JS

Comment: @HiteshModha didn't help

Comment: @HiteshModha can it be because of file location order? Like put the js file at the end of list or beginning

Comment: import js file in head of page.

Answer (score 1):

```
 if (pathname.substring(1, 3) == "eng") {


    $(submenuNew1[0]).attr("href", "/eng/about/info");
    $(submenuNew1[0]).children("h5").text("blah");
    $(submenuNew1[1]).attr("href", "/eng/about/info/1");
    $(submenuNew1[1]).children("h5").text("blah");
    $(submenuNew1[2]).attr("href", "/eng/about/info");
    $(submenuNew1[2]).children("small").text('blah');
    $(submenuNew1[3]).attr("href", "/eng/about/info");
    $(submenuNew1[3]).children("small").text('blah');
**}**
```

else if (pathname.substring(1, 3) == "fr") {

The brace after before else if is missing.

Comment: Jsfiddle console also says the same. Thought it was the issue. Can you  update Jsfiddle also?

Comment: Another brace missing after else if closing block. It should else if{ } });